# Access Active Storage models with Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to add the active storage models to active admin? I have tried to add them in the usual active admin way, however, the rails app just crashes.

Comment: Show first what you have tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few comments and a quick chat, here's the final solution:

ActiveStorage delivers active_storage_blobs, giving you an extra layer of information: metadata, url, redirects, booleans etc.

These ones are handled by ActiveStorage::Blob.

rails g active_admin:resource active_storage_blobs will throw an error. The reason is because ActiveStorage follows a different setup and ActiveRecord. In this case, get the resource directly from the Active Storage.

For now, the solution is:

```
rails g active_admin:resource ActiveStorage::Blob
```

This will display the blob data as an own index inside ActiveAdmin. Everything else should follow the same pattern as normal.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is useful to know for creating new objects. What I am looking to achieve is add the Active Storage models to Active Admin so I can view all the entries. So far I have tried the equivalent of `rails g active_admin:resource User` but I get an error and the server won't load.

Comment: Are you talking about how to display your current data? For example, if you a user model and you want to display them inside ActiveAdmin so that you can manage them?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, yes I am familiar with your suggestions. I am not able to add the Active Storage model to Active Admin. I have tried `rails g active_admin:resource Active_storage_attachment` and `rails g active_admin:resource Active_storage_blob` but it throws out errors

Comment: It doesn't makes sense what you are trying to do. Why do you want to add active storage attachment like so? So it seems that you want to add ActiveStorage to your ActiveAdmin, like i first assumed. You want to be able to upload images, files via ActiveAdmin correct? That means you need ActiveStorage. In this case, look at my first example. Thats how you do it. Have you any examples of your code? Or do you use GitHub? I could modify it so that you see how its done.

Comment: ActiveAdmin always needs a resource. The resource is coming from your Active Record. And ActiveStorage is attached to that ActiveRecord and not to ActiveAdmin. ActiveAdmin only reads/writes on what it gets by using resources. Therefore adding ActiveStorageAttachment to your ActiveAdmin wouldn't work. ActiveAdmin is not a model. You can only attach files via ActiveStorage by using a model, like stated in the Rails doc's.

Comment: I agree with you that to add files, the best way is as you have suggested. I want the active storage models inside Active Admin so that I can easily read/analyse the data. Active Storage has two Active Record models - active_storage_blobs and active_storage_attachments. I just want to be able to examine the tables in full as via the console isn't that user friendly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187484/discussion-between-prometheus-and-mrbiggs).